# Wierd Left align issue in Navigation bar HTML5 css

Tags: css, html, margin, nav

I am trying to align the navigation bar to the left of the container which is 950px wide, but it's still showing the margin on the left side. How do I align it to the left completely without specifying the left margin in negative?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDJA8/1/)**

**HTML5 code**

```
<div class="nav-holder">
    <nav class="container">
        <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marketing tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav>
</div><!-- nav holder -->
```

**CSS**

```
body{margin:0}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.container {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url('images/nav-bg.jpg') repeat-x;
}
.nav-holder nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.nav-holder li {
    float: left;
}
.nav-holder li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ff0202;
    padding: 4px 23px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
}
.nav-holder li a:hover,.nav-holder li.active a {
    background: rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/fDJA8/2/

Comment: there is still left margin you can see at the jsfiddle , thanks

Comment: Try to add `padding:0` to `.nav-holder li a `.

Comment: nope , still not working,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong, all lists (ul and ol) have default indents associated with them. Try adding a `padding: 0;` to your CSS rule for ul like below.

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `padding-left`

http://jsfiddle.net/fDJA8/4/

```css
ul {
    padding-left : 0px;
}
```